# C# XAML Pivot Data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, pivot, .net-6.0

I have a set of coordinates for each Coordinate Type

| CoordinateSet | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z50 | 123456 | 4567890 | 445.3 |
| Z51 | 234567 | 9876543 | 445.3 |
| LatLong | 112.45 | 83.250 | NULL |

I would like them displayed in a WPF Datagrid along with other data but flattened out.

| A | B | C | Z50 | Z51 | LatLong |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ??? | ??? | ??? | X Y Z | X Y Z | X Y Z |
|  |  |  | 123456 4567890 445.3 | 234567 9876543 445.3 | 112.45 83.250 NULL |

I have tried putting the XYZ Data as a datatable inside a datatable with columns of Z50, Z51, LatLong as typeof (DataTable) but this does not work.

The data only needs to be displayed, not edited.

Is this possible in WPF C#?

Regards

Comment: "I have tried putting the XYZ Data as a datatable inside a datatable with columns of Z50, Z51, LatLong as typeof (DataTable) but this does not work" - if done properly, DataTable should be the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work using a DataTable inside a DataTable.
Code below for reference.

```
CoordsDataTable = new();

    foreach (var coordset in DrillDesigns.Coordinates)
    {
        CoordsDataTable.Columns.Add(coordset!.CoordinateType!.CoordinateType, typeof(DataTable));
    }

    CoordsDataTable.Rows.Add();

    foreach (var coordset in DrillDesigns.Coordinates)
    {
        CoordsDataSet = new();
        CoordsDataSet.Columns.Add("X");
        CoordsDataSet.Columns.Add("Y");
        CoordsDataSet.Columns.Add("Z");
        CoordsDataSet.Rows.Add(coordset.X, coordset.Y, coordset.Z);
        CoordsDataTable.Rows[0][coordset!.CoordinateType!.CoordinateType] = CoordsDataSet;
    }
```